# How to CREATE TABLE AS SELECT on a stream?

Tags: ksqldb

CREATE TABLE AS SELECT can be done only with a grouping, but how then in the Base to organize a table (you need a simple table without aggregations / groupings) in order to supplement another stream with data?
As an example:
There is a stream A with fields (product, city_id).
We need a table (or something else) with fields (city_id, city_name) which is replenished by another thread.

And there is a stream that connects complements stream A with the name from the table through.

How can you organize data enrichment using an external directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LATEST_BY_OFFSET` aggregation to build a table of data in this way.

```sql
CREATE STREAM source_city_data 
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='source_city_data', FORMAT='AVRO');

CREATE TABLE city_data AS 
  SELECT city_id, LATEST_BY_OFFSET(city_name) AS city_name 
  FROM source_city_data
  GROUP BY city_id;
```